# ELI5: Why do they say that Israel would have been the fourth country to land a spacecraft on the Moon and why do they call it low cost?

Tags: the-moon, lunar-landing, lander, beresheet, chandrayaan-spacecraft

In the news they say that

> Israel hoped to become the fourth country to land a spacecraft on the Moon. Only government space agencies from the former Soviet Union, the US and China have made successful Moon landings.

E.g. [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/.premium-israel-s-lunar-spacecraft-will-attempt-historic-touchdown-tonight-1.7109263), [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-47879538)

Why don't they mention the Indian [Chandrayaan-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrayaan-1)?

The [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-47879538) that I quote here even provides a picture from NASA with the list of successful moon landings that includes a station from India.

Another question: why do they call it low cost? According to the same BBC article,

> The project has cost about $100m (£76m) and has paved the way for
>   future low-cost lunar exploration.

Wikipedia says that the cost of the Chandrayaan-1 project was US$54 million.

**Disclaimer**: I am not an Indian.

Comment: It's a good point you make. Presumably they are talking about soft landers, not impactors, though.

Comment: Note that the Israeli attempt is not being counted as a "landing".  This implies that crashes are not counted.

Comment: and Ben Voigt's point is exactly why the indian mission is not counted here

Comment: Usually it is claimed that Israel wanted to be the fourth to *soft land* a vessel. There are two reasons to omit the *soft*, either because you are a bit sloppy or because the author doesn't consider crashes to be landings. In this context, it is clear that the author meant to exclude crashes (which the impact of an impactor like Chandrayaan-1 is).

Comment: Isn't the answer here given by the keyword, "land"?

Comment: If you're going to count crashes as landings, Japan beat both India and China with the two [Hiten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiten) craft.  The ESA also crashed an impactor before India.  Here's a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spacecraft_on_the_Moon).

Comment: ^^^ and in fact, the guys in the control room said after the crash, "well, it makes us the seventh nation to put an object on the Moon, then". @DarrelHoffman

Answer (score 54):

Chandrayaan-1 hit the Moon at high speed and did not survive its "landing", which would have been much more difficult to engineer. (Its successor, Chandrayaan-2, which will actually land, is expected to cost \$125 million and has taken more than ten years so far, as opposed to the three years for Chandrayaan-1.)

As far as cost goes, besides India's own (still unlaunched) soft lander that costs \$25 million more than Israel's attempt, compare the costs of the US Surveyor program. NASA spent \$469 million in the mid 1960s to launch seven probes, five of which successfully landed. Most of that money went to developing the technology needed for all the probes to work, and each probe cost a small fraction of that to actually build. Adjusting that amount for inflation, you get almost \$3.8 billion in 2019 dollars. So if we had to start from 1960s technology and launch a new probe to land on the Moon, the cost would probably be somewhere around there. One might discount it by a few hundred million for the five extra probes, but that's still easily at least thirty times the pricetag on Israel's project.

Comment: I saw this in the NYTimes and remembered that you've reminded me once or twice about the em-dash. I thought you might find it interesting: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/14/style/em-dash-punctuation.html